# Power BI matrix - Subtract two (dynamic) corresponding columns using DAX

Tags: matrix, powerbi, dax, dynamic-columns

I have a single measure in the Power BI Desktop matrix below.
[image]

The measure comes from a single table, and is a sum of a column with numerical values.

The measure is:        SUM(Table[Column])

Column Group 1: Category

Column Group 2: Year

Column Group 3: Qtr (i.e. Q)

I have a scenario, in which our client wants to get the variance (difference) between **2020 Q1 of Category A** and **2020 Q1 of Category B**.

[image]

The new column is Q1 Variance.

In a similar manner I need the variance between 2020 Q2 of Category A and 2020 Q2 of Category B.

How do I get a new column in a matrix based on this scenario, where I subtract corresponding columns in a Year and Quarter?

Also there may be situation later in which Category A can have a year that Category B may not have.

For example, Category A may have **2018 and 2019**, while Category B may have **2017 and 2018**.

In this scenario, I will need the difference between the 2018 Quarters only, don't need any computation on 2017 and 2019.

Any ideas please, using DAX?

The Category selection happens via a Slicer.

Sometimes it may be Category A and Category B, other times it may be Category B and Category C, that are chosen from the Slicer.

The slicer will always choose **exactly** 2 categories at a time.

So, I cannot hard code anything. Everything is dynamic.

Category A may have 2018 and 2019,
while Category B may have 2017 and 2018,
while Category C may have 2019, 2020, 2021, etc.

Also, I might have to compare the corresponding months too. Say Jan 2019 of A will be subtracted from Jan 2019 of B (similar to the Quarter comparison).

I think we may need to use some variable to match the year, and then move to quarter, and later to month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have exactly two distinct categories, you can pick one using max and one using min and calculate the variance between the two.

```
Variance =
VAR Cat1 = MAXX ( ALLSELECTED ( Table1 ), Table1[Category] )
VAR Cat2 = MINX ( ALLSELECTED ( Table1 ), Table1[Category] )
VAR Sum1 = CALCULATE ( SUM ( Table1[Column] ), Table1[Category] = Cat1 )
VAR Sum2 = CALCULATE ( SUM ( Table1[Column] ), Table1[Category] = Cat2 )
RETURN
    IF ( ISBLANK ( Sum1 ) || ISBLANK ( Sum2 ), BLANK (), Sum1 - Sum2 )
```

This preserves the year and quarter/month context and only changes the category context to do the calculation.

Comment: Thanks Alexis; it makes sense. I will get back after trying.

Comment: Thanks very much Alexis; it works now; I used the idea you provided and made slight adjustments to suit my need; I also learned a good deal on ALLSELECTED DAX function. appreciate your help very much.

Comment: Another small question:  Am using the Power BI Matrix. So the new Variance measure shows as a column for each Category (group column). Is there any technique to show the Variance measure column under any one Category only ? Is there any hiding technique possible in Power BI using DAX?

Comment: Your small question is actually much more difficult and would need its own post.

Comment: ok, will post a new one; the data is fine with your approach; but the variance column is repeated for both categories (in the matrix), which is redundant.  i will inform you after I post a question on the matrix-redundant-column hiding part. Thanks again Alexis for your help.

Comment: Hello Alexis,  I have posted the matrix column hiding here.                                                https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65573297/power-bi-matrix-remove-repeating-column-of-a-group

Answer (score 0):

There is a function called SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR that works with time intelligence, maybe that could work for you.

Comment: I am actually not comparing a measure between two different years; rather it is compared in the same year (example: 2020 Q1 Vs 2020 Q1) , only that the Category varies (A Vs B Vs C......)